# Is Scrolling textview allowed in Google Glass

Tags: android-layout, google-glass

My app accepts a word and dishes out details from database. The contents is put in one text view each in three different sub menu. The content is slightly more than it can display in glass. Can I get a scroll on text view when a person moves his head up.

Any other suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to handle this in Glass is to show some of the text and offer a "Read More" menu item. (As well as a "Read Aloud" menu item to read it out.)

Comment: Thats good idea. I will provide Read More and try out Read Aloud as well. Thank You. Appreciate your suggestion.